# Can someone explain this excel worksheet formula in a logical progression?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to convert this Excel worksheet formula to Python and I don't fully understand what's going on. I understand the cell references in this code and the "if(logical_test,[value_if_true],[value_if_false]" format, but I get lost in this piece of code while trying to understand it:

```
=IF('Sales on Amazon'!$K2="Standard", IF(
    AND(
         IF(
            'Sales on Amazon'!$G2,
            14/16,
            12/16
            )
        >='Sales on Amazon'!$E2,
        MAX(
            'Sales on Amazon'!$B2:$D2
           )
       <=15,
       MIN(
           'Sales on Amazon'!$B2:$D2
           )
       <=0.75,
       MEDIAN(
              'Sales on Amazon'!$B2:$D2
              )
         <=12
       ),
       "SML STND",
       "LRG STND"
   ),
   IF(
OR(
   'Sales on Amazon'!$J2>165,
   'Sales on Amazon'!$E2>150,
   MAX(
       'Sales on Amazon'!$B2:$D2
      )>108
   ),
"SPL OVER",
 IF(
    'Sales on Amazon'!$J2>130,
   "LRG OVER",
   IF(
      OR(
         'Sales on Amazon'!$E2>70,
         MAX(
             'Sales on Amazon'!$B2:$D2
            )>60,
         MEDIAN(
                'Sales on Amazon'!$B2:$D2
               )>30
         ),
      "MED OVER",
     "SML OVER")
  )
))
```

Comment: I think something is wrong with this part right here.  IF(
            'Sales on Amazon'!$G2,
            14/16,
            12/16
            )
        >='Sales on Amazon'!$E2,Can you check and repost? Also can you put an inline copy of the formula in your post, as it makes it easier to copy and paste into Excel to try out.

Comment: Unless the value in G2 is a boolean, in which case then it is evaluating to either true or false. Could you also post a small sample of your data.

Comment: @AMR - any number will do. For all intents and purposes, Excel treats a zero as False and anything that is not false is True. Put `=AND(A1)` in B1 and see what it takes to get a False.

Comment: @andrewd12. If you think the answer I provided helps you out, given the time it took, I would appreciate it if you could mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: This was the best I could come up with. [Excel Worksheet Formula in a Logical Progression](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Excel_Worksheet_Formula_in_a_Logical_Progression.pdf). Note that I've renamed the worksheet to **aos** to reduce obfuscation.

Comment: That is really nice work @Jeeped.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fun.... So you have a data sheet named `Sales on Amazon` that this is referencing. That is where your data is.

1. If the value in column `K` equals the string "Standard" then **2 through 7** are your **`True`** condition for your `if` statement, **8 through 17** are your **`False`** condition.

**All of these need to be `True` to return a `True` for the `AND`**

2. If the value in column `G` is `True`, then `0.875`, else `0.75`, and if that is greater or equal to than the value in column `E`
3. And the `max` of the range of columns `B, C, D`, is greater than or equal to `15`
4. And the `min` of the range of columns `B, C, D`, is less than or equal to`0.75`
5. And the `median` of the range of columns `B, C, D`, is less than or equal to `12`

**This is the evaluation of the `AND`**

6. Then if 2, 3, 4, and 5, are `True`, `SML STND`
7. Else `LRG STND`

---

**This ends the `True` condition of the first if statement that starts the formula.**

---

**This begins the `False` conditionof the first if statement that starts the formula.**

---

**Only one of these need to be `True` for the `If` statements's condition to be `True`.**

8. If the value in column `J` is greater than `165`
9. Or if the value in column `E` is greater than `150`
10. Or the `max` of the range of columns `B, C, D`, is greater than `108`
11. Then if any either `8, 9, or 10` evaluate to `True` then `SPL OVER`
12. Else if they are all `False`, then if the value of column `J` is greater than 130 then `LRG OVER`

**ELSE 13 through 16 are the `True` condition for 12, which is the `False` condition for 8, 9, and 10.**

**Only one needs to return a true for the whole Or statement to be `True`, and  17 is the `False` condition.**

13. If the value in column `E` is greater than `70`
14. Or the `max` of the range of columns `B, C, D`, is greater than `60`
15. Or the `median` of the range of columns `B, C, D`, is greater than `30`
16. Then if any either `13, 14, or 15` evaluate to `True` then `MED OVER`
17. Else `SML OVER`

And there you have it.

To test it out, just look at the data and work through these steps and see if the answer you get is the same as the value in Excel.

---

The reason I say columns is that I saw that the formulas had `$B2` `$D2`, etc. So I made the assumption that this formula is copied down a column for a range of data. It however only reverences the values for those columns in the same row.